# How to remove default talk back response on particular views

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

So basically I am implementing talk back feature for my android app.
There is Edit Text View for user to write there phone number and then there is a button for sign up. If user hasn't given any phone number the Sign Up Button is disabled.
When the Button is disabled it the talk back should say "Sign Up Button Disabled, Please enter a valid mobile number." But since there is default string which talk back is saying at the end i.e : Button Disabled.
How to remove the default string being said for a particular view.

```
verifyButton.disable()
verifyButton.contentDescription = requireContext().getString(R.string.sign_up_button_disabled_phone_number_accessibility_label)
```

Comment: please add code for further info..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by attaching an [AccessibilityDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate) to the view:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(submitButton, object: AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
        host: View,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
    ) {
          super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
          if (!submitButton.isEnabled)
              info.stateDescription = getString(R.string.accessibility_button_not_enabled_reason) //"Please enter a phone number"
      }
})
```

This will update every time the state of the view changes so you won't need to manually do it on validation.

This will announce:

> "Please enter a phone number, [Button Text], Button, Disabled"

So the user will still be aware of the button and it's intention and additionally why it's disabled!

Comment: Just a note - the order of the elements in the announcements is a user preference [user state, description, type, state]